# How to load and execute an assembly into memory in C# from a binary array as a resource

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I am trying to achieve is protect a customer-developed video game(with Unity3D) executable with a license, that expires after a certain period of time. The thing is, my team has no longer any access to the game executable, so recompilation of the game executable is out of the question. That is why I decided to embed the game executable as a resource into a program "wrapper", that first checks if the client license is valid (through on-line verification - I used System.Net and System.Net.Http to achieve that). After the license server returns an "OK" response to my desktop game "wrapper", I would like to start the game executable in memory, without writing it to the disk.

Here is the sample code for loading my executable from a resource, but it gives me "badimageformatexception" during runtime:

```
Stream stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("LicenseServerClient.testBinary.exe");
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);//Assembly.Load(bytes);// The debbuger stops here, throwing a "badimageformatexception" 

assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[0]);
```

Now, if you think that there is a better way to achieve the whole licensing architecture under these constraints, please feel free comment and give feedback.

Comment: If you embedded your resource (I guess because of namespace included in name) then you may just put it in a resx file and it's accessible with Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.MyAssemblyName); As side question: are you sure it's a .NET assembly? If not then you can't load it...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti unity3d uses .NET from MONO, not from microsoft - the compatibility is somewhere between .net 2.0 and .net 3.0 (i think mono is already .net 4.0 compatible, but unity uses an older version)

Comment: The game was build with Unity 4.6, and for the license server I use .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use your Unity3d executable as a reference in your project? First, attempting to do so would answer the question of whether the binary is even a valid assembly as far as .NET is concerned. Based on the error message, I doubt it is and nothing you can do will change that (Unity is *based on* Mono, but as I understand it, standalone Unity programs are not managed code assemblies).

If you can reference it from your own project, then you ought to be able to load the assembly in-memory from a resource. Hence my skepticism about that being possible.

Given the assumed incompatibility, a better approach is probably to write the binary back to disk (i.e. as a temp file), and then just execute it as an external process. Hosting a non-managed-code binary inside your managed process is likely to be infeasible.

Of course, doing so will make it easier for people to bypass your wrapper. If they examine the running processes, it won't be hard to trace back the game process to the file you wrote, and they can just make a copy of the file at that point.

But then, your current intended approach isn't much harder to hack. It's not going to be hard for someone with just a little more computing skills to use the right tool to find the `Assembly.Load()` call, find the resource you're running the game from, and then extracting that resource as the standalone game without the wrapper.

Bottom line: without modifying the game code itself, if you intend to execute the game's code on the client's machine, there's not much you can do to enforce your license programmatically. You'll be able to slow down the most naïve users, but that's about it. (Of course, that's true for even the most sophisticated copy protection, with only a relatively small degree of difference, so I guess you might consider any license-enforcement scheme that has any effect at all to be "good enough" :) ).

Comment: I am aware of the fact, that advanced users and professionals will be able to bypass the security checks. The idea is to make it hard enough, so that it is not worth their time.

One thing I do not get is this - an executable is a sequence of binary instruction - '0's and '1's. So why it is so difficult to just interpret it as a sequence of bytes, load it in a byte array(as I am trying to do) and execute it in memory and why it is infeasible?

Comment: Every single bit of data in a computer is "a sequence of binary...0's and 1's". The problem comes when it's time to _interpret_ those binary 0's and 1's. There are many kinds of executable formats on Windows; heck, even within the class of managed assemblies, there are different, mutually incompatible formats (e.g. x64 vs x86). `Assembly.Load()` can only load an assembly in the format of the currently running managed process. Just as interpreting iso-8859 as if it were UTF16 text will result in gibberish, so too would interpreting one executable format as another. So .NET won't let you.